# why does this work in a shell for loop but not by itself

Tags: bash

why does this work

```
for X in A* ; do cp $X/output.txt output/$X.txt ; done
```

but not this

```
cp A*/output.txt output/A*.txt
```

For copying the output.txt file from multiple folders called A1, A2, A3, A4, etc. into a combined folder called "output" giving each text file the name of the folder it came from.

Comment: I would imagine because cp is not in and of itself iterative, and because since A* is a wildcard on the left, but can't be treated as one on the right (there is no parallel enumeration, and wildcards only work for input, not output, where there are entirely ambigious) so it becomes a literal 'A*', not A1, A2, etc. some looping construct is required to expand both instances of A* to expand them, and keep them in synch for each iteration. X is a variable that is updated on each loop. A* is not.

Answer (score 5):

Because the shell expands the `A*.txt` part to *multiple* paths before it's passed to the command that is being invoked (`cp` in this case).

This means that in the first case, if you have files named A1.txt, A2.txt, A3.txt and A4.txt and directories A1, A2, A3 and A4 each containing output.txt it expands to *something like*:

```
for X in A1.txt A2.txt A3.txt A4.txt ; do cp $X/output.txt output/$X.txt ; done
```

and in the second case, it expands to:

```
cp A1/output.txt A2/output.txt A3/output.txt A4/output.txt output/A*.txt
```

where the `output/A*.txt` part may or may not expand depending on whether there exists anything in the `output` directory matching the glob. If it does, it gets even worse, like:

```
cp A1/output.txt A2/output.txt A3/output.txt A4/output.txt output/A8.txt output/A9.txt
```

Since `cp` when given multiple source files wants a destination *directory* at the end, it doesn't know how to handle this and simply throws up its hands and gives you an error instead.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that, if there are more than two arguments to `cp`, the last one **must** be a directory. The [cp Man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cp) states:

> Synopsis
>
> cp [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST
>
> cp [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
>
> cp [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...
>
> Description
>
> Copy SOURCE to DEST, or multiple SOURCE(s) to DIRECTORY.

The command you wrote,

```
  cp file1 file2 file3 file4
```

was intended to mean

```
 cp file1 file3; cp file2 file4
```

but it does not, for the reason above. The for loop instead produces exactly the 2 statements immediately above, which is what you really want.